# Compute: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{ (\sqrt2+1)^{2n} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \{ (\sqrt2+1)^{2n} \}$$
where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. I need some hints here. Thanks.

Comment: I think $\{(\sqrt2+1)^{2n}\}=2^n\sqrt2$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider $$ (\sqrt2+1)^{2n}  +  (\sqrt2-1)^{2n} $$

Try to show that it is an integer and hence this fractional part you are looking for is $1 - (\sqrt2-1)^{2n}$ Now the limit becomes easy.

Comment: got it! Thanks!

Comment: It's limit is coming out to be 1, but fractional part can't be 1, so the result is 0 or 1?

Comment: I don't see why the fact that no element in the sequence can be 1 should stop the limit from being 1.

Comment: okay!, i got your point :).Thanks!!